# ListView Items overlap with other Items on really big lists

Tags: uwp-xaml

When testing a simple ListView with 100000 items the ListView starts to overlap with items beneath it. Is there a way around this?

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="500"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,10,10,10" x:Name="pageTitle" Text="Page 1" />
    <ListView  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,10,10,10" x:Name="itemListView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,10,10,10" Text="Bottom Text" />
</Grid>
```

The code behind:

```
    private ObservableCollection<string> _items = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ObservableCollection<string> Items
    {
        get { return this._items; }
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        FillItems();
    }

    private void FillItems()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            Items.Add($"Item {i}");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Loading all the elements at the same time will cause performance issues. you can use incremental loading to load elements as the scrollbar progresses. By implementing [`IIncrementalSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/incrementalloadingcollection#example). You can set how many items can be fectched

> The GetPagedItemsAsync method is invoked everytime the view need to
>   show more items.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Person>> GetPagedItemsAsync(int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        // Gets items from the collection according to pageIndex and pageSize parameters.
        var result = (from p in people
                        select p).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize); 

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I implemented the incremental loading example you pointed out above, unfortunately it still goes funny after about 50000 lines.

Comment: Then you can try UI virtualisation as suggested in Microsoft docs for item collection crossing 1000 items https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/optimize-gridview-and-listview#ui-virtualization